# Using exec 'continue' in loop

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why using `pass` works in this code but `continue` throws an error: `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`?

```python
f = 'pass'  # Works
f = 'continue'  # Fails

for i in range(10):
    if i < 5:
        exec f
    print i
```

Just to provide some context, I was checking if a keyword could be stored in a variable:

```python
def magic_print_i(f):
    for i in range(10):
        if i < 5:
            exec f
        if i % 3:
            continue
        print i

magic_print_i("continue")
```

Comment: Offtopic: what do you use this for?

Comment: I was just experimenting to see if variables could be used in place of keywords. The context was I had a range of options in a loop which could all be assessed if f='pass' or all skipped if f='continue'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `exec` doesn't carry the context over to the statement being executed.

`pass` can be used *anywhere*, so the context doesn't matter. `continue` can only be used in the context of a loop, but that context is *not* available to `exec`.

You can only use `continue` in an exec statement if the *loop itself* is *also* part of the executed code:

```
f = 'for i in range(10): continue'
exec f
```

In other words, you can only use `exec` for *complete* statements, where a single `continue` (or `break`) is not complete.

Comment: I see, is there anyway to use a variable to hold a key word such as continue, and then use the variable instead?

Comment: @kezzos: there is not, not when that statement requires the wider context.

Comment: @kezzos: what problem are you really trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

a `continue` isn't complete. It's like the other half of a `break`. Whereas `exec` executes complete commands, as like in `pass`

Answer (score 0):

To apply exec on a dynamically selected keyword within a loop context, use string formatting:

```
selected_keyword = 'break'

exec(
f'''
for i in range(5):
    #do stuff
    {selected_keyword}
''')
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. The `break` would've worked already since the loop is inside the `exec`

Comment: @Nelson It is needed if you want to be able to pick between continue/break/pass for some reason and need to pick one in advance (I don't see the use case)